# Handler not being called (how to wait for resource initialization onCreate)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, handler

I'm struggling with initializing a SQLite db in my activity.  I want to access the DB immediately, to populate a listview.  The idea is for the app to start a worker thread to open the DB, then wait on the thread to finish, calling a handler which will set dbExists true, and exit the while loop. In this code, the app hangs, the handler is never called (I checked with log messages):

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

static boolean dbExists = false;
static Handler dbHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        Log.d("handler", "this log message is never printed");
        dbExists = true;
    }
};
static SQLiteDatabase db;

public void onCreate(Bundle sIS) {
    dbHelper = MySQLiteOpenHelper(this);
    Thread dbOpener = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            dbHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }
    });
    //my strategy to avoid NPE thrown when trying to use db before it exists
    while(!dbExists) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    //do something with the db
}
```

However, I have discovered that if I put `dbExists = true;` *inside* the `run()` method of the thread, this whole setup works no problem.

Questions:

1. why is my handler not called?  I understand the default constructor uses the default looper of the thread, since its the main thread, the main `Looper` is already running, right?  I'm not getting any exceptions or warning messages of any kind in the log.
2. does this solve the problem of not blocking the UI thread?
3. if I can access a variable in one thread `dbExists` from another thread, why bother to use the handler at all?

Comment: When you use SQLiteOpenHelper, simply calling getWriteableDatabase or getReadableDatabase if the db doesn't exist it will either be created or upgraded - in either case the operation is synchronous and a valid db will be returned. If it already exists you'll obviously also get a valid database. I'm not sure why you think you have to wait.

Comment: I only do this because the documentation says not to call this method from the UI thread.

Comment: I've always ignored that. I suppose it depends on how complex the creation/ upgrade process is. I use an AsyncTask for the initial creation and an IntentService for daily data imports. Also the only upgrades I do to the schama are with new releases and handled by an AsyncTask.

Comment: Thinking about it, create a simple layout with a TextView saying something like "Processing data..." and use the ListView setEmptyView()` method. Then use an AsyncTask (with indeterminate ProgressDialog) to call getWritableDatabase and then make the query and set the ListView adapter. That's basically what I do but with a very simple database I've run it on the UI thread without problems.